# Webpack public path to assets add one more parametr

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

use vue + webpack , all is ok , but when go to child route, then press F5 webpack or vue change path.

Example.

child route `localhost:8080/user/config/`

assets path after F5 become `localhost:8080/user/static/css` but have need not to change path assets and leave it like `localhost:8080/static/css`

vue js config :

```
dev: {
env: require('./dev.env'),
port: 8080,
autoOpenBrowser: true,
assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
// assetsPublicPath: '/',
proxyTable: {},
// CSS Sourcemaps off by default because relative paths are "buggy"
// with this option, according to the CSS-Loader README
// (https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#sourcemaps)
// In our experience, they generally work as expected,
// just be aware of this issue when enabling this option.
cssSourceMap: false
```

}

Comment: Where is your index.html? Can you please provide your index.html?

Comment: i have found it was problen in component inporting in that free template, anyway thx